# Python: What is for ... in

Tags: python, list, dictionary, iterable

In page 29 of the third edition of the Python Cookbook, the author makes the following statement:

> "... might also be done by creating a sequence of tuples and passing them to the `dict()` function. For example:
>
> > `p1 = dict((key, value) for key, value in prices.items() if value > 200)`

The author's referral of the argument passed to the `dict()` constructor as a "sequence" kinda got me wondering... what exactly *is* `for ... in ...`? It isn't an expression is it? One can't just type into a Python interpreter: `for x in (1,2,3)` and receive a result? The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list) for `list()`, for example suggests constructor expects an iterable but it's unclear to me what's going on.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions

Comment: You can do `for x in (1,2,3):print(x)` yes, the iterable is a tuple here

Comment: True. But you can do this: `(x for x in (1,2,3))` and is referred to as a generator sequence / expression.  A basic example of the `dict` example in question.  And just to note; you’re missing a closing `)` in your example, which is why it doesn’t make sense.

Comment: @MichaelSilverstein the example shown *isn't* a comprehension, although you could write the same functionality as a dict comprehension.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to clarify what parts about that statement you *do* understand? Do you know what an iterable is? Are you familiar with ``for`` loop *statements*? Did you consult the documentation?

Comment: You have a small typo where the bracket is supposed to end :)

Comment: Also take note: The quote cited is not strictly correct. This does *not* pass a *sequence* of tuples to ``dict``. The result of the ``... for ... in ... if ...`` is a generator of tuples, or more generally only an iterable/iterator of tuples.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi it's not a sequence [in the Python sense](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-sequence), no.

Comment: @S3DEV: Whoops, thanks for the typo catch. Yes, there should be an ending parenthesis.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi. D'oh. I just forgot what the syntax is for a generator function, and was a bit thrown off when he called it a sequence. You figured it out, I think I took it a bit too literally. Thank you!

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks for refreshing me with the docs/noticing that I was being a literal (pun intended) dumb-dumb!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dict` can takes an iterable of key/value pairs to construct a new instance. The expression

```
(key, value) for key, value in prices.items() if value > 200
```

is a *generator* expression; the result is a value of type `generator`, which (when iterated over) yields those tuples from `prices.items()` whose second element is greater than 200.

Another way to create a `generator` is with a generator function:

```
def foo(p):
    for key, value in p.items():
        if value > 200:
            yield key, value

d = dict(foo(prices))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
p1 = dict((key, value) for key, value in prices.items() if value > 200)
```

is the equivalent of:

```
p1 = {}
for key,value in prices.items():
    if value > 200:
        p1.update({key, value})
```

`prices` is a `dict`, so prices,items will return something like this:

`dict_items([(key1, value1), (key2, value2)])`

Comment: Why the expensive `p1.update({key, value})` instead of the cheaper `p1[key] = value` -- I see people do this but I never understand why.